# Swiper Js - Only start slider when the device width is less than or equal to 515

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using this slider: https://swiperjs.com/api/

Now, I want to start the slider when the device width is equal to or less than 515. to do this I am using this JS code but it's not stopping the slider when the device is greater than 515. It should start the slider when the device width is less than or equal to 515:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        // when window width is >= 320px
        515: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 20
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for less than or equal to, if im correct, i think you do <= or <==

idk it's been a while since i used java script

Comment: I have used that code between a condition but still, it's not working. like `var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
if (width < 515) { ..... }`